# How to create intervals of 100 based on a column in a query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a table with below structure:

```
create table item_test
(item_id       varchar2(10),
 item_row      number)
```

Sample data is like below , please note that numbers in `Item_Row` column starts at 1 and increases by 1 to a number without any gaps. What I need to do is to create intervals of 100 `([1-100] , [101-200] , [201-300] ,......)` for each `Item_Id`.

```
   Item_Id       Item_Row    
 ------------   ----------- 
    A               1           
    A               2            
    A              ...
    A              ...
    A              236  /* Item_Row starts from 1 and continues to 236 */

    B               1
    B              ...
    B              ...
    B              173  /* Item_Row starts from 1 and continues to 173 */
    
    C               1
    C               2
    C              ...
    C              ...
    C              300  /* Item_Row starts from 1 and continues to 300 */
```

The result will be like below:

```
  Item_Id       RowNum_From     RowNum_From
 ------------   -----------     ----------- 
     A              1               100
     A             101              200
     A             201              236

     B              1               100
     B             101              173
     
     C              1               100 
     C             101              200
     C             201              300
```

Is there any specific function for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to use the `trunc` function.

Here's a solution using pure SQL:

```
create table item_test
(item_id       varchar2(10),
 item_row      number);

insert into item_test
select 'A', level from dual connect by level <= 236
union all
select 'B', level from dual connect by level <= 173
union all
select 'C', level from dual connect by level <= 300;
commit;

select item_id, min(item_row) as item_row_from, max(item_row) as item_row_to
  from item_test
 group by item_id, trunc(item_row-1, -2)
 order by item_id, trunc(item_row-1, -2);
```

And the result:

```
ITEM_ID    ITEM_ROW_FROM ITEM_ROW_TO
---------- ------------- -----------
A                      1         100
A                    101         200
A                    201         236
B                      1         100
B                    101         173
C                      1         100
C                    101         200
C                    201         300

8 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 4):

Really nice question - thought provoking - +1!

To solve this, I did the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e01ac30be23c7766922904980be6a77)):

- I borrowed the setup code from the accepted answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316437/34007).

```
insert into test
select 'A', level from dual connect by level <= 25
union all
select 'B', level from dual connect by level <= 18
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25;
```

- You really should be providing fiddles with sample data - you have > 1,300 points on dba.se so you should know this! It's a courtesy to those trying to help - it eliminates duplication of effort and provides a single point of truth for the question and would have eliminated the problem I had.

```
SELECT
  c, fval1, lval2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    c, i, 

    FIRST_VALUE(i) OVER (PARTITION BY c, TRUNC((i - 1) / 10) 
      ORDER BY c, i ASC) AS fval1,
    
      -- the default frame clause for window functions
    
    FIRST_VALUE(i) OVER (PARTITION BY c, TRUNC((i - 1) / 10)  ORDER BY c, i ASC
      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  AS fval2,

      -- the default doesn't work for the LAST_VALUE() fuction - you have to do it
      -- this way.    

    LAST_VALUE(i) OVER (PARTITION BY c, TRUNC((i - 1) / 10)  ORDER BY c, i ASC
      RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)  AS lval2

  FROM 
    test
) TAB
GROUP BY c, fval1, lval2
ORDER BY c, fval1;
```

Result:

```
C   FVAL1   LVAL2
A       1      10
A      11      20
A      21      25
B       1      10
B      11      18
C       1      10
C      11      20
C      21      25
```

The interest here is that this could potentially provide more scope for analysis - with different parameters and/or different window functions.

Change the `10` in `TRUNC((i - 1) / 10` to a `7` and you can do a weekly analysis for example - see the last snippet [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa0819c9551eb52d35304dff5da4083f).